# Switch statement not returning values

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

My first time using `switch` and I'm having some trouble returning anything. As a test I'm taking a string and, based on the character that is tested, console logging some string output.

```
function pairElement(str) {
switch (str) {
    case "A":
    console.log("some things")
    break;
    case "G":
    console.log("some more things")
    break;
}
}
pairElement("ACG");
```

The cases are of the same value type so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't returning because `ACG` does not equal `A` or `G`. switches need to use exact matches.

Comment: Switch matches each case via `===` (strict comparison).

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test is not valid based on the values you are handling in your switch statement. You only handle cases for `A` and `G` but you passed `ACG`. Switch had no way to go if any of the cases specified do not match since you also are missing the default case. Your test would be valid if:

```js
function pairElement(str) {
switch (str) {
    case "A":
    console.log("some things")
    break;
    case "G":
    console.log("some more things")
    break;
}
}
pairElement("A"); // some things - valid
pairElement("G"); // some more things - valid
pairElement("ACG"); // switch case and no default - NOT valid
```

Adding a default would give you:

```js
function pairElement(str) {
switch (str) {
    case "A":
    console.log("some things")
    break;
    case "G":
    console.log("some more things")
    break;
    default:
    console.log("something ELSE")
}
}
pairElement("A"); // some things  - valid
pairElement("G"); // some more things - valid
pairElement("ACG"); // something ELSE - valid
```

Now there is also the question what exactly did you expect when you tested for a multi character string vs single one. Handling the single chars in your switch kind of eludes to you expecting the string passed to your function to be `tested` char by char and if so you need to state that since that changes the question/requirement.

Updating for the scenario where you want char by char:

```js
function pairElement(str) {
 str.split('').forEach(function(v) {
  switch (v) {
   case "A":  
   console.log("some things")
   break;
   case "G":
   console.log("some more things")
   break;
   default:
   console.log("something ELSE")
  }
 }
)
}
pairElement("ACG"); 
// some things
// something ELSE
// some more things
```

Comment: I did not consider ```switch``` treating the word as a single element. In order to accomplish pushing certain characters into an array I would need to split the word and iterate through the individual characters (possibly using filter, etc).

Comment: I updated my answer with the char by char scenario. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

You should add a **`default`** case since you are passing "ACG" which is not of any case. Switches in any programming language needs a matching case.

**DEMO**

```js
function pairElement(str) {
switch (str) {
    case "A":
    console.log("some things")
    break;
    case "G":
    console.log("some more things")
    break;
    default:
    console.log("some things + some more things")
}
}
pairElement("ACG");
```

Comment: the string could use `split` and he could loop over each letter.

Comment: Yes, what I was thinking is to loop through and access each character with split, possibly utilizing ```filter``` or something similar in order to  push to a final array. I now understand JS looks to the word as a single element and if I do not use "split" and further break down into single characters the code will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a string of length three, there is the first thing to modify. The second is just to must put a default evaluation to in case of any of your cases matches your desired criteria which is the case right now.

```
function pairElement(str) {
    switch (str) {
        case "A":
            console.log("some things");
            break;
        case "G":
            console.log("some more things");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default");
            break;
     }
}
```

Check [MDN Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) information

Answer (score 1):

Switch uses strict comparison (===, in other words it has to match exactly) so in this case "ACG" does not exactly match "A" or "G" and since nothing exactly matches the switch does nothing.

Add a case for "ACG" to get the switch to execute something when "ACG" is passed.  You can also add a default case and the switch will execute that case if nothing else matches:

```
function pairElement(str) {
  switch (str) {
    case "A":
      console.log("some things")
      break;
    case "G":
      console.log("some more things")
      break;
    case "ACG":
      console.log("ACG exactly matches this case")
      break;
    default:
      console.log("nothing matched so default executed");
      break;
  }
}

pairElement("A"); // some things
pairElement("G"); // some more things
pairElement("ACG"); // ACG exactly matches this case
pairElement("this won't match anything"); // nothing matched so default executed
```